# Retrieving a subset of vertices from TitanDB through Mogwai

Tags: python, titan

Supposing I had the following `Vertex` class definition:

```
from mogwai.connection import setup
from mogwai.models import Vertex, Edge
from mogwai import properties

setup('localhost')

class Food(Vertex):
    name = properties.String(default='banana')
    taste = properties.String(default='sweet')
```

And supposing I have a bunch of vertices in my DB of different foods. How would I retrieve only vertices with a certain taste?

I know one method is to just do:

```
ingredients = [food for food in Food.all() if food.taste=='sweet']
```

But this seems really inefficient because you will be querying for all vertices and then filtering them in python. I've looked at the docs, mogwai source code, and learned how to do simple Gremlin queries, but I'm a beginner to graph DBs and it's a bit hard to connect the dots.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it didn't occur to me to look at how `all()` was defined, but learned how to load query results from that function. So here's what worked:

```
from mogwai.connection import execute_query

flavor_type = 'sweet'
rs = execute_query("g.V.has('food_taste','{}').toList()".format(flavor_type))
objects = []
for r in rs:
    objects += Food.deserialize(r)
print(objects)
```